# How to creat a dictionary from a set?

Tags: python, dictionary, set

I get a set from a text file which are new words. Such as `{'multiple','description','loop','baboo',……}`. I have defined a function that can get the word's definition from the internet. The function is `dictionary()`, which can get the explanation from internet but should wait 3-5 seconds because the speed is very slow. How to get a word from set and let the `value = dictionary(word)`? So I can get the `dict()={Word：dictionary(word),...}` written in my text file. It's very useful to study new words.

Comment: Hi welcome to SO! We are not a code writing service, please review [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your question. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

```
words_definitions = {word: dictionary(word) for word in words}
```

This is basic dictionary comprehension. As for adding parallelism, for an IO-bound task like this [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) could work well.